# Trouble getting Google Maps Java API 3.8

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, google-api

I am trying to find a jar that corresponds to [this javadoc](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/3.8/index.html) but I am having trouble.  Google returns [this GitHub page](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api) but that is not what I want.  How can I find a jar that corresponds to an API reference that I like when there is no link within the javadoc and search engine results are confusing?

Answer (score 0):

From messing with the Javadoc URL I was able to find this in the tree, which looks like what you need:

http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/releases/maps/1.1/

If you're looking for a JAR, you may have to assemble it yourself, but they're nice enough to include the Eclipse files

Comment: but the version seems to be 1.1.  i need 3.8

Answer (score 0):

The source is in that GitHub. It's just not in a jar. Go to git-maps-api/src/main/java and you'll find the code.

https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/tree/master/gwt-maps-api/src/main/java

Comment: oh but it seems to be there but it still doesn't match the javadoc:  https://github.com/downloads/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/Apis_Google_Maps-3.8.1.jar